# $Ax = b$ & $Ax + b$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, control-theory, affine-geometry

Ask a dumb question but confuse me long time.

The following is what I know:

1st case
$Ax = b$ is an affine set in $x$,i.e. $\{x | Ax = b\}$, and it is linear in $x$.
2nd case
$ f(x) = Ax + b$ is an affine function. It is not linear because of $b$.But $f(x) = Ax$ is linear in $x$.

My question is I am still confused about both of them, can anyone provide a more mature way to seperate both of them? What is the main difference (or application) between them?

Comment: I am not very sure what you meant. I think the set $\{Ax=b\}$ comes from $f(x)=Ax$. So if you compare $f(x)=Ax$ and $f(x)=Ax+b$, one represents proportionality, the other does not. Or think about it in 1D, one passes through the origin, the other does not.

Comment: I should say in this way: affine is linear (roughly speaking, Ex: in control theory), but $Ax + b$ is not linear. I am confused of both.

Comment: Isn't it by definition? A linear map has the property: $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y), f(cx)=cf(x)$.

Comment: Yes, so $Ax+b$ is not linear

Comment: Indeed, $Ax+b$ is affine but not linear. Regarding your previous comment, affine IS NOT linear, roughly speaking. Linear transformations are affine, but not the other way around. Is your confusion about what affine transformations are?

Comment: @sleevechen Yes, but $g(x) := f(x) - b$ is linear